# There is error while sending mail in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Getting Error while sending mail help me to solve this problem.

The following SMTP error was encountered: 0 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

> Error
>
> User-Agent: CodeIgniter Date: Fri, 25 Aug 2017 09:16:26 +0000 From:
>   "xxx"  Return-Path:  To: xx@x.com Reply-To: "XXX"
>    Subject:
>   =?utf-8?Q?=57=65=65=6B=6C=79=20=43=6F=75=72=73=65=20=42=61=74=63=68=20=52?= =?utf-8?Q?=65=70=6F=72=74?= X-Sender: xx@xx.com X-Mailer: CodeIgniter X-Priority: 3 (Normal)

CODE

```
    $config['protocol'] = "smtp";
    $config['smtp_host'] = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $config['smtp_port'] = 587;
    $config['smtp_user'] = "abc@gmail.com";
    $config['smtp_pass'] = "123";
    $config['charset'] = "utf-8";
    $config['mailtype'] = "html";
    $config['smtp_crypto'] = "ssl";
    $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
    $config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
```

Comment: There's no enough info to help you

Comment: check it now @MasivuyeCokile

Comment: `Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.` - Do you have any mail software? Sendmail, SSMTP, etc. installed?

Comment: If you experience problems connecting to your mail servers, make sure that your SMTP and POP3 server port settings are correct.

Comment: No Dan i don't have any mail software

Answer (score 0):

You can use **SwiftMailer** for sending email through Codeigniter.

- First download the swiftmailer project from Github using [this link](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer)
- After downloading, copy only the **lib** folder to codeigniter's **Library** folder and rename the folder's name like swift_mailer ( or anything you wish)
- Now create a model in Codeigniter's Model Folder named like **Model_Email_Sending.php**
- Now Paste the code given here to that file. ( replace the email and password and mailing port given from Cpanel of your server )

  ```
  <?php
  defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
  require_once APPPATH . 'libraries/swift_mailer/swift_required.php';
  class Model_Email_Sending extends CI_Model
  {
     function __construct()
     {
        parent::__construct();
     }
    function send_applicant_information_to_mail($applicant_id,$password,$first_name,$last_name,$email_id)
    {
        $system_email = "noreply@yourdomain.com";
        $email_msg = "Welcome to yourdomain.com ".$first_name . ' '.$last_name ."<br />";
        $email_msg .= "Thanks For applying<br />";
        $email_msg .= "Your application ID : " . $applicant_id . "<br />";
        $email_msg .= "Your application Password : " . $password . "<br />";
        $email_msg .= "You can Login now using this credential and can check your status.<br />";
        $to_name = $first_name;
        $from = $system_email;
        $from_name = 'Domain TEAM';
        $email_sub = "Application Information";
        $email_to = $email_id;

        $this->do_email($email_msg, $email_sub, $email_to, $to_name, $from, $from_name);
    }
     function do_email($msg=NULL, $sub=NULL, $to=NULL, $to_name=NULL, $from=NULL, $from_name=NULL)
    {
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'To: '.$to_name.' <'.$to.'>' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: '.$from_name.' <'.$from.'>' . "\r\n";

        $from = 'noreply@yourdomain.com';
        $from_name = 'Domain TEAM';
        $fromsend = array($from => $from_name);


        $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('mail.yourdomain.com', 587); //By default Cpanel use this port for email . You have to find your domain's port yourself
        $transport->setUsername('noreply@yourdomain.com');
        $transport->setPassword('yourpassword');
        $swift = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

        $message = new Swift_Message($sub);
        $message->setFrom($fromsend);
        $message->setBody($msg, 'text/html');
        $message->setTo($to);

        if ($recipients = $swift->send($message, $failures))
        {
            return 'ok';
        } else {
            echo "There was an error:\n";
            print_r($failures);
            return 'no';
        }

        $tha = mail($to, $sub, $msg, $headers);

        if(!$tha){
            return 'no';
         } else {
            return 'ok';
        }
     }
  }
  ```

**N.B:**

> You must replace your domain email and password with the code's demo
>   email and password. And most importantly GMAIL or Other email
>   providers doesnt support SMTP right now. So, You have to use third
>   Party providers like SwiftMailer or SendGRID I used filename similar
>   to my code. So please careful with the code.

*A demo function named **send_applicant_information_to_mail()** is given which will need to be called from Controller to send mail. Write your own functions relevant to you by yourself in the model.*

Hope this work for you :)

Answer (score -1):

There is an error in the `line 211` of

`"classes\Swift\Transport\EsmtpTransport.php".`

change

```
return $this->params['sourceIp'] ?? null;
```

by

```
return $this->params['sourceIp'];
```

There are also missing files in the

package: `swift_init.php` and `swift_required_pear.php`

Comment: Are you seriuosly answering this question

Comment: This answer is such a low quality post, please reconsider everything.